# Fluent NHibernate and HasMany mapping

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have following problem using fluent nhibernate and HasMany. I've search through google and SO for similar problem but any of solutions I've found does not solve my problem.

I have following entites mapped (I omitted most properties for clarity):

PaymentSchedule.cs

```
public class PaymentSchedule
{
    public virtual BinaryId Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<PaymentToSchedule> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

PaymentToSchedule.cs

```
  public class PaymentToSchedule
  {
    public virtual BinaryId Id { get; set; }        

    public virtual PaymentSchedule PaymentSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping files

PaymentScheduleMap.cs

```
public class PaymentScheduleMap : ClassMap<PaymentSchedule>
{
    public PaymentScheduleMap()
    {
        Table("A_Payment_Schedule");
        Id(x => x.Id, "A_Payment_Schedule_Id").CrmId();
        HasMany<PaymentToSchedule>(x => x.Payments).Table("A_Payment_To_Schedule").KeyColumns.Add("A_Payment_Schedule_Id").Fetch.Select();
    }
}
```

PaymentToScheduleMap.cs

```
public class PaymentToScheduleMap : ClassMap<PaymentToSchedule>
{
    public PaymentToScheduleMap()
    {
        Table("A_Payment_To_Schedule");
        Id(x => x.Id, "A_Payment_To_Schedule_Id").CrmId();            
        References(x => x.PaymentSchedule, "A_Payment_Schedule_Id");            
    }
}
```

Basically I want to fetch list of PaymentToSchedule entites when loading PaymentSchedule object. Now, to do this, I must use such queries:

```
var paymentSchedules = dataAccess.Session.QueryOver<PaymentSchedule>().List();
```

and for each of the payment schedule

```
 var paymentToSchedule = (from pts in dataAccess.Session.Query<PaymentToSchedule>()
                                                where pts.PaymentSchedule.Id == ps.Id).
                                                      ToList<PaymentToSchedule>();
```

This works fine, but is there a way to fetch list of PaymentToSchedule entites while querying PaymentSchedule?

Answer (score 0):

```
var paymentSchedules = dataAccess.Session.QueryOver<PaymentSchedule>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Payments).Eager;
    .List();

// payments are already initialised, you can safly do
var allPayments = paymentSchedules.SelectMany(ps => ps.Payments).ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work. It results in an empty collection, while executing sql select statement results in 1 returned row. Also, i'm using ShowSql() option while session factory configuration and nhibernate executes proper sql to fetch the PaymentToSchedule entitites... but does not seem to populate the collection.

Comment: then there is something wrong. can try without `.Fetch.Select()` ?